# Do sub commands in discord.py command groups inherit decorators of the parent command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do a series of commands in discord.py where the parent command is "set," with the child command being "channel" or some other group/command. As you can probably guess, I don't want just anyone to be able  to set a welcome or goodbye channel. So my question is this: if I have this code...

```py
@bot.group()
@has_permissions(manage_server=True)
async def set():
  # enter command functionality here
```

...and I create a sub command/group in that group...

```py
@set.group()
async def channel():
  # enter command functionality here
```

...will the permissions be inherited by the sub groups/commands?

Comment: yes, the permission will be inherited in child command too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the permissions are inherited from decorators.